# Storing Byte arrays and strings in the same file

Tags: java, file-io

I am making a program which requires me to store login information for users.  I already have the code set up which creates a hashed `Byte[]` array of their passwords and salts them with another `Byte[]`.  I would like to store their username, their password, and their salt in the same file, preferably something like `username,password,hash`.

All I have found so far are examples of storing only a Byte array.  If anyone could point me in the right direction for writing and reading files like that, it would be great.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Could create an Object to hold all three and write that serialized Object to the file

Comment: I don't agree with serializable object...if it changes you couldn't be able to read already stored data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would probably be to just convert the byte arrays to text using base64 or hex (*not* calling `new String(bytes)`) and then just use a property file or any other text storage scheme you fancy.

You *could* go the other way, and store everything in a binary format (e.g. using a length-prefixed message for both bytes and strings) but my experience is that the readability of text files is huge boon to development.